# the argument type ‚CheckIn‘ cannot be assigned to parameter type ‚() -> CheckIn‘

Tags: dart

I’m actually struggling to understand this type error.

Anyone has an Idea how I can correct the code? Thanks

```
CheckIn checkin1 = new CheckIn(location1, dt);
CheckInMonths checkInMonths = new CheckInMonths();
```

the error occur at this line, **something is wrong with checkin1**:

```
checkInMonths.months.putIfAbsent(month,checkin1);
```

other code:

```
class CheckIn {
  Location location;
  DateTime dateTime;

  CheckIn(this.location, this.dateTime);
}

class CheckInMonths {
  Map<Month, CheckIn> months = new Map();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `putIfAbsent` has to be a function returning a CheckIn Value (https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.Map#id_putIfAbsent)

```dart
checkInMonths.months.putIfAbsent(month, () => checkin1);
```